# How to make container take full width in phone devices using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

No matter how I try in my CSS file, the container can't take full width in phone device.

my CSS file:

```
@media (max-device-width: 1024px) {

.col-sm-2{
    width: 100%;

}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}


.col-sm-10 {
    width: 100%;
}


}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<h1 >Profile</h1>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `container-fluid` class instead of `container`, or if would prefer you can use the `sm`, `lg` and so on suffixes , like `container-sm`

[image]

See the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#containers)

Answer (score 0):

Try container fluid

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<h1 >Profile</h1>
</div>
```

or add !important to @media like this

```
@media (max-device-width: 1024px) {

.col-sm-2{
    width: 100%;

}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}


.col-sm-10 {
    width: 100% !important;
}


}
```